# Codeigniter: getting select option from form

Tags: forms, codeigniter, select, post

I'm trying to get the option item selected in a form select element using Codeigniter...

I have a controller named results with this code in it

```
//get form data
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
   $data['searchdata'] = array(
      "ionum" => $this->input->post('ionum'), 
      "thisdb" => $this->input->post('thisdb')
   );
}
```

which loads into a view, the 'ionum' is a text input which I can retrieve, the 'thisdb' is the select, I get no results for it...how do I pull that?

Comment: Your code here is mangled but I'm assuming you're having no problems actually hitting the controller and dumping the results of the array you're building. That said, your code for accessing POST vars looks correct, so I would think the next place to look would be your form markup. Append your markup to this post if you can't figure it out.

Comment: You'll have to post the html too for us to be any help.

Comment: also, the beauty of $this->input->post is that you don't have to check for request method, really, the variables will be assigned false if the fields are empty. I'd like to see the view AND how you call it.

Answer (score 7):

Ensure your html looks like:

```
<form action="<?= site_url('mycontroller/myfunction');?>" method='post'>
    <input type='text' name='ionum'/>
    <select name='thisdb'>
    <option value='db1'>DB1</option>
    <option value='db2'>DB2</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Then in your controller, you would write:

```
class Mycontroller extends CI_Controller{
    function myfunction(){
        $p = $this->input->post();
        if($p){
            //you can now access the ionum and thisdb... try echo
            echo $p['ionum'];
            echo $p['thisdb'];
        }
    }
}
```

It is unnecessary to run the `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")` conditional. Just check if `$p` exists as above.